# How to get data from HDFS? Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to Hadoop. I ran a map reduce on my data and now I want to query it so I can put it into my website. Is Apache Hive the best way to do that? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that Hive is a batch processing system, which under the hoods converts the SQL statements to bunch of MapReduce jobs with stage builds in between. Also, Hive is a high latency system i.e. based on your dataset sizes you are looking at minutes to hours or even days to process a complicated query.

So, if you want to serve the results from your MapReduce job output in your website, its highly recommended you export the results back to a RDBMS using [sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org) and then take it from there.

Or, if the data itself is huge and cannot be exported back to RDBMS. Then another option you could think of is using a NoSQL system like [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org).

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Hadoop!

I *highly* recommend you watch [Cloudera Essentials for Apache Hadoop | Chapter 5: The Hadoop Ecosystem](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/resources/library/training/cloudera-essentials-for-apache-hadoop-webinar-series-4-of-6-getting-to-know-the-components-of-the-apache-hadoop-ecosystem.html) and familiarize yourself with the different ways to transfer data inbound and outbound from your HDFS cluster. The video is easy-to-watch and describes advantages / disadvantages to each tool, but this outline should give you the basics of the Hadoop Ecosystem:

1. [Flume](http://flume.apache.org) - Data integration and import of flat files into HDFS. Designed for asynchronous data streams (e.g., log files). Distributed, scalable, and extensible. Supports various endpoints. Allows preprocessing on data before loading to HDFS.
2. [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org) - Bidirectional transfer of structured data (RDBMS) and HDFS. Permits incremental import to HDFS. RDBMS must support JDBC or ODBC.
3. [Hive](http://hive.apache.org) - SQL-like interface to Hadoop. Requires table structure. JDBC and/or ODBC is required.
4. [Hbase](http://hbase.apache.org) - Allows interactive access of HDFS. Sits on top of HDFS and apply structure to data. Allows for random reads, scales horizontally with cluster. Not a full query language; only permits get/put/scan operations (can be used with Hive and/or Impala). Row-key indexes only on data. Does not use Map Reduce paradigm.
5. [Impala](http://impala.io) - Similar to Hive, high-performance SQL Engine for querying vast amounts of data stored in HDFS. Does not use Map Reduce. Good alternative to Hive.
6. [Pig](http://pig.apache.org) - Data flow language for transforming large datasets. Permits schema optionally defined at runtime. PigServer (Java API) permits programmatic access.

Note: I assume the data you are trying to read already exists in HDFS. However, some of the products in the Hadoop ecosystem may be useful for your application or as a general reference, so I included them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking to get data from HDFS then yes, you can do so via Hive.
However, you'll most beneficiate from it if your data are already organized (for instance, in columns).

Lets take an example : your map-reduce job produced a csv file named wordcount.csv and containing two rows : word and count. This csv file is on HDFS.

Let's now suppose you want to know the occurence of the word "gloubiboulga". You can simply achieve this via the following code :

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
  word STRING,
  count INT,
  text2 STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/wordcount.csv'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE data;   

select word, count from data where word=="gloubiboulga";
```

Please note that while this language looks highly like SQL, you'll still have to learn a few things about it.